# No pop-up message on android device when sending notification with pusbots

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add push notifications with pushbots on my android app. Everything works, message is received, sound alert, but no message window/popup. I am a bit new to this and stuck (pushbots support is not being very responsive or explicit) so please help.

This is last part from logcat when receiving message:

```
D/ActivityThread﹕ SVC-Destroying service: com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService@4220ca30
D/ActivityThread﹕ SVC-STOP_SERVICE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@4212e1f8
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=16: exiting
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=16: bye!
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the push notification, it is up to you to build the notification you'll present to the user.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I used the pushbots plugin, with cordova. The answer I got from pushbots is: 'Your app is missing Android Support Library 4. Please, make sure it's there, this is why you are not seeing the pop-up.' But, it is actually there, so no clue honestly...

Comment: Then simply add `support-v4` library :) https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4

Comment: It is installed, but I am reinstalling it again. Also I am confused about using android support repository or -v4 or both. That is, with Android Studio :-)